# Google - Fetch calendar events from users using service account

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

i've been digging for some days but i'm not getting the right answer and i'm getting confused, the more i read, me more confused. This is the situation

- The feature needs to get user consent (client) and be able to fetch user's calendar events each some time, e.g 2 weeks (in server side) in a nextjs application
- My company has a google service account
- Users are normal google users

What i understood is :

1. I need to configure google service account oauth and extract client_id and secret values to be able to create a consent auth that will allows users to give consent using calendar scope (pretty sure of this)
2. I need to create google client programatically using google compute which will allow my account to fetch user calendar information (not sure here)

I've started from a POC using my own account in which i've been able to solve this using step 1) and redirecting from consent to an internal url that get users token and save it in database, after that, hitting and endpoint using the token from the database to fetch events.

But they told me that company need to use a service account and that confused me a lot.

i will appreciate any help.

Comment: By any chance have you already checked this documentation discussing [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-overview)?

Comment: Hello Valencia. My understanding is: 1) Create your service account and give it the appropriate access. 2) Download the JSON and p12 file (private key) from this account. You will need this later. 3) Share your personal calendar with your service account email. 4) Use the JSON file and private key to log in as the service account. Theoretically, this is all you need to access your personal calendar.

Comment: But there's still one more thing left, you need to add your personal calendar to the service account's calendar list. And it's exactly at this point that I'm stuck, I've spent many hours trying to figure out how to do this but so far with no result. Maybe we can help each other figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lastly i make it work just configured oauth and linking my service-account with aws appflow service.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please tell how did you link service-account with AWS Appflow. I am trying same but Appflow uses OAuth creds for creating connection but how it will link to the service account?